# Difference between [ and [[ in if statements

Tags: shell-script

The following code

```
if [ $a == "apple" ];
then
    echo "True"
else
    echo "False"
fi
```

outputs `"True"` (`"False"`) if `a="apple"` (`a="plum"`). The comparison fails if one uses wildcards:

```
if [ $a == "appl"* ];
```

and is fixed if one replaces `[` by `[[`:

```
if [[ $a == "appl"* ]];
```

What is the difference between `[` and `[[` in `if` statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `[` is a command (basically a variant of the `test` command). `[[` is a builtin in many shells.
- When you write `foo*` inside `[...]` [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) (aka globbing) occurs; while inside `[[...]]` [pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) occurs.
- `[[` is more powerful and capable than `[` but should not be used if portability is a concern.
- `[` and `[[` are not part of the `if` syntax, you can use them as in `[ "$exit" = 'yes' ] && exit`.
- Inside `[...]` you should prefer `=` instead of `==`. As far as I know, the second one is accepted in many shells but is not POSIX-compliant.

By the way, I recommend you to double-quote your variables even if you really know how [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) will behave.